# SQL generated scripts always use CAST on numeric values

Tags: sql-server

I wonder if there's someone who could explain the behavior of SSMS generated scripts or point me out to some documentation that explains it since I struggled finding and answer.

I have a table with some char and numeric fields filled with data.
When exporting this table including data ( Under TASKS-Generate Scripts ) in the .SQL file when looking at the insert part, there's always a CAST used on all numeric values. Example: CAST(66.000000000000000 AS Numeric(38, 15)).

There's no actual issue since it just works well, but I would really like to know the explanation behing this, why is Microsoft using CAST automatically even though the original data already is in numeric format. Compatibility reasons?

Thank you very much.

Looked over the whole list on advanced options when exporting and I cant find anything related to it. Nor I can find anything related to this in Microsoft documentation.
I was expecting theres someone that could point me on the right direction to help find the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It uses `CAST` because by default SQL Server treats values with decimal points as the smallest `NUMERIC` value which can contain the value.

To see this, check out this query:

```sql
SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(66.000000000000000,'BaseType') [BaseType],
SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(66.000000000000000,'Precision') [Precision],
SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(66.000000000000000,'Scale') [Scale]
```

The result is:

| BaseType | Precisions | Scale |
| --- | --- | --- |
| numeric | 17 | 15 |

So the value would have been treated as `NUMERIC(17,15)`. To match the data type of the column, it uses `CAST` to be explicit about the data type and avoid conversion issues.